# Is it possible to read an excel sheet and display its contents purely on front-end?

Tags: excel, angular, typescript

I am thinking if i can read the contents of an excel sheet using XLSX and display its contents on front-end.

I tried reading a file using

```
tmpArray= [];
reader.onload = function(e : any) {
   var data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
   var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'array'});

   let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

   // sample values //
   let desired_cell = worksheet['B5'];
   let cellB16 = worksheet['B16'];
   // sample values //
   let desired_value12 = (cellB16 ? cellB16.v : undefined);
   tmpArray.push[desired_value12];
};


but outside this onload function, array of tmpArray don't exist anymore.
So what i wanted is to access the tmpArray and it's contents after the onload function. Is there any work around to do this?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-and-export-excel-demo)

In your typescript file

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

onFileChange(evt: any) {
    /* wire up file reader */
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      /* read workbook */
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });

      /* grab first sheet */
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

      /* save data */
      this.data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 }));
      console.log(this.data);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
}


export(): void {
    /* generate worksheet */
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(this.data);

    /* generate workbook and add the worksheet */
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

    /* save to file */
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.fileName);
}
```

Comment: Can i not save the worksheet into a new file? all i want to is to display the values during the onload

Comment: What does {header : 1 } actually do? sorry i don't understand the readme or index.d.ts for XLS @dasunse

Answer (score 0):

try this - excel file Read

> import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

```
 this.ExcelData = [];
        this.ngxLoader.start();
        this.file = event.target.files[0];
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (e) => {
          this.arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
          var data = new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer);
          var arr = new Array();
          for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
          var bstr = arr.join("");
          var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
          var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
          var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
          let jsondata = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { raw: true });
          this.ExcelData = jsondata;
        }
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
        this.file = null;
```

Comment: do I have to convert the values to json? like is it a must to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Please make the following change and you will be able to access the value of `tmpArray` from anywhere.

```
tmpArray; // changed here and moved it to outside the function

let self = this; // please note this change
reader.onload = function(e : any) {
   var data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
   var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'array'});

   let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

   // sample values //
   let desired_cell = worksheet['B5'];
   let cellB16 = worksheet['B16'];
   // sample values //
   let desired_value12 = (cellB16 ? cellB16.v : undefined);
   self.tmpArray = desired_value12; // changed here
};
```

Comment: It's just that `this` keyword evaluates to the value of the ThisBinding of the current execution context. So you will have to have a simple work around to access the value outside that function

Comment: @Opkko Lim did you try this ?

Comment: I can't seem to bind it like this. what i wrote was just an abstract version. it says tmpArray doesn't exist in the component.

Comment: @OpkkoLim updated the answer, please move the `tmpArray` to the top outside the function definition inside the component class ( just like any normal variable declaration )

Comment: Hi @Joel Joseph, I came to the same conclusion as well, however, when i push values into my tmpArray, it says the values inside are undefined. resulting in some issues.